# FullCalendar, dropped fixed date via externel events

Tags: events, fullcalendar, drag

i'm using externel event component of fullcalendar like below 
http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.7.1/demos/external-dragging.html

`// this is my droppable event.
        drop: function(date) {
            //e.g. starttime="09:00 11:00"
           starttime=$(this).text().split(" ")
           tempDate = new Date(date);

           var start=moment(tempDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
           var start=start+" "+starttime[0]; 
           var end=start+" "+starttime[1]; 

           var newEvent = {
              title:start + " ~ " + end,
              start: start,
              end: end,
              allDay: false,
           };


           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, true);


         }`

one of external event sources, i've changed only drop event part like above. because I would like to apply the date by only my **fixed date** via starttime. 
 
but there were created another elements like positioned date and my **fixed date**.

 do you know how to appear only fixed date? 
06:00 ~ 08:00 was positioned date.
09:00 ~ 11:00 was fixed date.
this is my screenshot.
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please try to rephrase your question

Comment: sorry unclear message. I mean hope to drag and drop my left side element "09:00 11:00" to right side calendar of "Sun 5/15" section anywhere. above sample, although i've dropped my element on "6am" part. just hope to be created that element only 9am to 11am.